# cURL Submitting POST fields after page load ( curl_exec )?

Tags: php, curl, html-parsing, captcha

I have to create a bot to collect some data from my college website , it uses simeple login with regno and captcha fields , they dont use real captcha , its a fake one ( can be seen in page source ) . So my idea is to use a DOM Parser and fetch it from  eg

Im a using PHP-Curl to do this job .
My Code:`

```
<?
$ch = curl_init();
$captch = i will get the value from DOM Parser ( But here is the problem , i have to get it before even executing the page !! ) 
$fields = "regno=11BTA00&captcha=$captcha";
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$loginurl);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The Problems is once i run curl_exec , get captca by parsing , to submit it i need to curl_exec again which leads to reloading of captcha ..

Any workaround for this ? other than cURL ? Im ready to use another library

Comment: Why don't you use another cURL request to get the captcha value and then pass it in your post fields?

Comment: the first cURL request gives me one captcha value , but cant submit as post to another curl_exec because this new request has its captcha value changed .

Comment: I Guess i have to use PHPQuery along with curl

Comment: What would your browser do?  It takes at least 2 requests to login, once to load the form and get the captcha, and then again to submit the form and pass along the captcha.  Use cURL, you don't need PHPQuery or any other libraries to do this.

Comment: @drew010 : i hope i can do it with cURL , i used PHPQuery only for parsing ..Please Check this pic for and help
http://i.imgur.com/p8g7q.jpg

Comment: Should be possible, probably not much help one can provide without knowing the URL or how the site login works.  On another note, while it probably isn't the reason the code isn't working, but I don't think you should have any `"` characters in your `$fields` post string.

Comment: @drew010 i have trimmed certain fields , yea i guess i have to escape "" , please have a look at source code : 
http://i.imgur.com/BTzEu.png 
I still get the same page with different captcha than the result_submit type page :/

Comment: @drew010 . Thanks , its working now , its because of the $fields ..my stupidity with "" .